# Can I make a t-shirt design matching others

Tags: copyright

So if I see a simple t-shirt design on the internet, with a normal phrase. for example lets use, "Live Laugh Love" and I copy that design. Am i opening myself up to a lawsuit if I sell it?

The design matches someone else's, however the phrase is common so all that is being copied is the font used and a square around it.

I feel like I did a poor job of explaining and I cant seem to think of a good way to put this. But I guess the question is. What is the threshold of creativity?

Answer (score 1):

If their design is copyrighted yes you are breaking the law.
http://blog.kunvay.com/3-common-questions-t-shirt-design-copyright-law-answered/

The box and font are their design.